# Spree - Issue in product image variants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I have an issue in Spree product image variants in product details page.

My Setup versions:

```
Rails version: 6.0.3.2
Ruby version: ruby 2.7.1p83
spree (4.1.7)
spree_api (= 4.1.7)
spree_backend (= 4.1.7)
spree_cmd (= 4.1.7)
spree_core (= 4.1.7)
spree_frontend (= 4.1.7)
spree_sample (= 4.1.7)
```

I have taxon as **categories** -> **women** -> **skirts** and one product named **Flared Midi Skirt** with 3 variants as below:
[image]

When i upload 3 images to all variants as below then its working fine:
[image]

and all 3 images are shown for all variants as below:
[image]

Now, if i change variant of image 3 to color black as below:
[image]

then the issue is that no image appears in color red for any size selected/unselected even though we have 2 images attached to **all** variants as below:
[image]

and only image 3 is shown when black color is selected a below:
[image]

So, as per my understanding, image 1 and 2 should appear in all 3 variants and image 3 should be added in color black variant.

Second try:
If i attach image 2 to variant with color red and size S as below:
[image]

then no image appears on any color(red/black) or any size even we select it or not in product detail page as below:
[image]

There is no error in browser console as well as in rails logs.

So, Have i misunderstood variant and images concept or is there an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

you must upload images for each variants,

if you have 3 images for each option,
2 colors, 2 sizes you should upload in total

2x2x3 = 12-images

Comment: I had a talk with one of QA of spree. He informed that its a bug in spree. I have created an issue in github: https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/10479